# Accessing parameters in Nancy After hook

Tags: c#, lambda, nancy

I would like to generate the response in the after hooks of my module. Since I need to store the response (generated by my route and other hooks) somewhere, I attach it to `parameters`. However, accessing them in the after hook does not work:

```
After += ctx => // <- below errors
{
    ctx.Response = Response.AsJson(ctx.Parameters.Response);
};
```

> Error 1   Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'Nancy.AfterPipeline' and 'lambda
>   expression'
>
> Error 2   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nancy.AfterPipeline'
>   because it is not a delegate type

How can I make this work? Or is there any alternative way to do it? Note that using just `ctx.Request` doesn't work for me because I need to access other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Session` to store parameters for later use in After hook. For example, lets have simple class

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
  public string Name{ get; set; }
  public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

In module, we can assign user to `Session` like this

```
Post["/user"] = x =>
{
    var user = this.Bind<User>();
    Session["User"] = user;

    return View["User", user];
};
```

And in After hook, use Session to create response

```
After += ctx =>
{
    ctx.Response = Response.AsJson(Session["User"]);
};
```

Note: `Session` are not enabled by default, so you need to enable them in Bootstrapper

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
  protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
  {
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    CookieBasedSessions.Enable(pipelines);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `Context.Items` would be a much better place to stick stuff that's only needed for a given request. A) They're always on, unlike sessions, B) It's designed for this exact usage, and doesn't get stored between requests.